# Signal r notification glyphicon bell mvc 5

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I am new in `MVC`. I saw many tutorials related to `signalR` to show real time notification but I can't meet my requirement with those tutorials. I wrote the same code in this youtube link - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AF9toV3EfnI&t=749s still nothing happened.

What I want is when I insert new project on database It should notify on glyphicon bell and pop down what data is inserted. I added `Owin Startup` class, `NotificationHub` Class also wrote code in Global.asax

On **Layout Page**

```
<li>
     <span class="noti glyphicon glyphicon-bell"><span class="count">&nbsp;</span>
     </span>
         <div class="noti-content">
            <div class="noti-top-arrow">
            </div>
                  <ul id="noticontent"></ul>
         </div>
</li>

<script src="~/scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
    <script src="~/scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .noti-content {
            position: fixed;
            right: 100px;
            background: #ff0000;
            border-radius: 4px;
            top: 47px;
            width: 250px;
            display: none;
            border: 1px solid azure;
        }

        ul#noticontent {
            max-height: 200px;
            overflow: auto;
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
            padding-left: 20px;
        }

            ul#noticontent li {
                margin: 3px;
                padding: 6px;
                background: #ff0000;
            }

        .noti-top-arrow {
            border-color: transparent;
            border-bottom-color: black;
            border-style: dashed dashed solid;
            border-width: 0 8.5px 8.5px;
            position: absolute;
            right: 32px;
            top: -8px;
        }

        span.noti {
            color: #2A3F54;
            margin: 15px;
            position: fixed;
            right: 100px;
            font-size: 18px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        span.count {
            position: relative;
            top: -3px;
        }
    </style>
```

**Jquery Code** is

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
             //click on noti icon
            $("span.noti").click(function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            $('.noti-content').show();
            var count = 0;
            count = parseInt($('span.count').html()) || 0;
            //only load noti if not already exist
            if (count > 0) {
                updatenotification();
            }
            $('span.count', this).html('&nbsp;');
        })


      function updatenotification() {
            $('#noticontent').empty();
            $('#noticontent').append($('<li>Loading...</li>'));

            $.ajax({
                type: 'Get',
                url: '/Admin/GetNotification', //getnotification is jsonresult action on admin controller
                success: function (response) {
                    $('#noticontent').empty();
                    if (response.length == 0) {
                        $('#noticontent').append($('<li>No Data Available...</li>'));
                    }
                        $.each(response, function (index, value) {
                            $('#noticontent').append($('<li>New Project ' + value.project_id + '(' + value.title + ') added by ' + value.client_name</li>'));
                        });

                },
                error: function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            })
        }


        //update noti count
        function updateNotificationCount() {
            var count = 0;
            count = parseInt($('span.count').html()) || 0;
            count++;
            $('span.count').html(count);
        }

        //signal r js code to start hub and send recieve notification
        var notificationHub = $.connection.notificationHub;
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            console.log('notification hub started');
        });

        //signalr method for push server message to client
        notificationHub.client.notify = function (message) {
            if (message && message.toLowerCase() == "added") {
                updateNotificationCount();
            }
        }
    })
</script>
```

On **NotificationComponent**

```
public class NotificationComponent
   {
    public void RegisterNotification(DateTime currenttime)
    {
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqlconstring"].ConnectionString;
        string sqlCommand = @"Select [project_id],[title],[client_name] from  [dbo].[Project] where [p_assign_date] > @p_assign_date";

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlCommand, con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_assign_date", currenttime);
            if (con.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                con.Open();
            }
            cmd.Notification = null;
            SqlDependency sqlDep = new SqlDependency(cmd);
            sqlDep.OnChange += sqlDep_OnChange;
            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {

            }
        }
    }

    private void sqlDep_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
        {
            SqlDependency sqlDep = sender as SqlDependency;
            sqlDep.OnChange -= sqlDep_OnChange;

            var notificationHub = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationHub>();
            notificationHub.Clients.All.notify("added");

            RegisterNotification(DateTime.Now);
        }
    }
    public List<project> GetNotification(DateTime afterdate)
    {
        using (aftermidEntities dc = new aftermidEntities())
        {
            return dc.projects.Where(a => a.p_assign_date > afterdate).OrderByDescending(a => a.p_assign_date).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

on **Admin Controller**

```
public JsonResult GetNotification()
    {
        var notificationRegisterTime = Session["LastUpdated"] != null ? Convert.ToDateTime(Session["LastUpdated"]) : DateTime.Now;
        NotificationComponent NC = new NotificationComponent();
        var list = NC.GetNotification(notificationRegisterTime);
        //update session here to get new notification
        Session["LastUpdated"] = DateTime.Now;
        return new JsonResult { Data = list, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }
```

on Logs Its only show signal r is started. The program runs but doesn't do anything when the project is inserted.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the the method

```
public void Hello() 
{ 
    --Your Code--
}
```

you can can do it by making a server call in your `hub.start()` function.

The same way as you make it from `Hub` to connect to `client` as below.

```
notificationHub.Clients.All.notify("added");
```

you need to Update this.

```
var d = new Date();
var month = d.getMonth()+1;
var day = d.getDate();

var currentdate = d.getFullYear() + '/' + ((''+month).length<2 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' + ((''+day).length<2 ? '0' : '') + day;

var notificationHub = $.connection.notificationHub;
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        console.log('notification hub started');
        notificationHub.server.RegisterNotification(currentdate);
    });

//for calling hello() method you can do the same thing inside the above function notificationHub.server.Hello();
```

This might help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register your `client method` function before `start the connection`

```
//signal r js code to start hub and send recieve notification
//signalr method for push server message to client
notificationHub.client.notify = function (message) {
   if (message && message.toLowerCase() == "added") {
     updateNotificationCount();
   }
}

var notificationHub = $.connection.notificationHub;
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    console.log('notification hub started');
});
```

Comment: `notificationHub.client.notify` not executed because there is no event to call a `hub server function`, hence this function not getting called from the hub server.

Comment: I make a class of notificationHub class :hub  why it is not executed. can u please guide me where to edit on my code. thanks.

Comment: you have hubClass, that's Ok. But I don't see any code where you called hub server function like `notificationHub.server.yourFunctionName()`

Comment: I have edited notificationHub like  `public class NotificationHub : Hub
    {
        public void Hello()
        {
            this.Clients.All.Hello("added");
        }
    }`                                    but this is not working.